# compute the rate in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like this :

```
date      isF  
190502     1 
190502     0 
190503     1 
190504     1 
190504     0 
190505     1
```

I would like to compute for each date the rate of "isF" when isF =1.
The expected result is :

```
 date  rate
190502     0.5 
190503     1 
190504     0.5 
190505     1
```

I tryed somethong like this but here i compute the sum, how can I do to compute the rate? :

```
stats_daily_df = (tx_wd_df
             .groupBy("date", "isF")
             .agg(# select 
                when(col("isF") == 1, (sum("isF")).alias("sum"))  
                .otherwise(0))   # else 0.00
                  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, Below can help:

```
df.groupBy('date').agg((f.sum('isF')/f.count('isF')).alias('rate')).show()
+------+----+
|  date|rate|
+------+----+
|190505| 1.0|
|190502| 0.5|
|190504| 0.5|
|190503| 1.0|
+------+----+
```